# Where is the Benefactor?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

I'm in the Aldmeri Dominion and am in Vulkhel Guard. The hooded figure told me to go see the benefactor, but the map tells me to get on a boat to Davon's Watch. I looked online and it says he should be on the Interim Suitor, but he isn't. Where is he? Is he in Davon's Watch?

Answer (score 1):

The location varies depending on your alliance:

- Aldmeri Dominion (Alliance) = inside The Interim Suitor ship at the Vulkhel Guard docks in Auridon.
- Daggerfall Covenant (Alliance) = inside the Patheirry House near the southeastern gate in the city of Daggerfall in Glenumbra.
- Ebonheart Pact (Alliance) = inside The Sadreno House by the bridge that goes over the two ponds in Davon's Watch city in Stonefalls.